# jQuery: Building up ul from json objects seperated by specific key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My ajax function gives back several JSON objects that have the following pattern:

```
var data = [
    { 'category': 3, 'name': 'Max' },
    { 'category': 1, 'name': 'John' },
    { 'category': 2, 'name': 'Mary' },
    { 'category': 2, 'name': 'Dennis' },
    { 'category': 1, 'name': 'Louis' }
];
```

Objects with the same category can have different names.

My goal is to build up a list based on these objects SORTED by category with jQuery. Here is what the list should finally look like:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="category-divider">1</li>
    <li class="element">John</li>
    <li class="element">Louis</li>
    <li class="category-divider">2</li>
    <li class="element">Mary</li>
    <li class="element">Dennis</li>
    <li class="category-divider">3</li>
    <li class="element">Max</li>
</ul>
```

What is the fastest and most flexible way to achieve building up this list based on an array like the one provided above?

Comment: What part of your code is not working ?

Comment: So far I only have this code: "var arrCat = [];

for (i=0; i < data[i].length; i++) {

// put categories in array
arrCat.push(data[i].category);


}

// get unique categories
var arrUniqueCat=arrCat.filter(function(itm,i,a){
    return i==arrCat.indexOf(itm);
});" I do not really know how to proceed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = [{
    'category': 3,
    'name': 'Max'
}, {
    'category': 1,
    'name': 'John'
}, {
    'category': 2,
    'name': 'Mary'
}, {
    'category': 2,
    'name': 'Dennis'
}, {
    'category': 1,
    'name': 'Louis'
}];


var list = $("<ul></ul>") // create list
var groupedData = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // group names by category
    groupedData[data[i].category] = groupedData[data[i].category] || []; // check if it exists, if not set it as empty array
    groupedData[data[i].category].push(data[i].name)
}

var categories = Object.keys(groupedData).sort(function(a,b){ return a -b}) // sort categories

for (var j = 0; j < categories.length; j ++) {
    var cat = categories[j]
    var category = $("<li class='category-divider'>" + cat + "</li>") // create category divider
    for (var i = 0; i < groupedData[cat].length; i++) {
        category.append("<li class='element'>" + groupedData[cat][i] + "</li>") // add names
    }
    list.append(category) // add category to list
}
$("body").append(list) // add list to body
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```